# ASP.NET Core routing middleware to place tenant name in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to write a webapp that uses tenants and am wondering how I can write a middleware to add the tenant name to the current URL.

This is a sample that I have so far and it doesn't work at all.

This is the route that I declare:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "tenants",
  template: "{tenantName}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

This is placed in the Configure section in my Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        var additionalPath = "/TenantName" + originalPath;
        context.Request.Path = additionalPath;
        await next();
    }
});
```

If I load up my application and log in, it shows this:

> https://localhost:44365/Applications/Applications

instead of

> https://localhost:44365/TenantName/Applications/Applications

I can manually add TenantName and it works but if I move to another page, it loses it again.

EDIT:

I tried creating a custom route builder but it doesn't work if my url is like this

> https://localhost:44365/TenantName/Applications/Applications/12345

```
app.UseRouter(routeBuilder => {
    var template = "{tenant}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}";
    routeBuilder.MapMiddlewareRoute(template, appBuilder => {
        appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) => {
            var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
            context.Request.Path = getNormalizedPath(routeData);
            await next();
        });
        appBuilder.UseMvc(rb => {
            rb.MapRoute(name: "tenantRoute", template: template);
        });
    });
});

private string getNormalizedPath(RouteData routeData)
{
    var tenant = routeData.Values["tenant"];
    var area = routeData.Values["area"];
    var controller = routeData.Values["controller"];
    var action = routeData.Values["action"];

    var url = "/" + tenant + "/" + area + "/" + controller + "/" + action;
    return url;
}
```

I have also placed this before my normal app.UseMvc();

Comment: have you tried doing this operation inside `public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)`

Comment: Hello! I don't quite understand what you mean? I don't think I can use that inside my Configure section?

Comment: sorry, but this is another way to register a middleware, you will create a extension method and call it in your configure method `IApplicationBuilder UseClientNameMapper(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)`. In startup configure method `app.UseClientNameMapper();`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you have any samples I can follow? I don't really understand what you're putting.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{tenantName=test}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

After this your your site will open like:

https://localhost:44365/TenantName/Applications/Applications

instead of

https://localhost:44365/Applications/Applications

**Update:** tenant name by default is test but can be passed from route at any place. There are multiple ways to do that, available on web. A simple example can be like:

```
[Route("{tenantName = TEST1}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Here tenant name is test1, url is like:
https://localhost:44365/test1/Applications/Applications

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. But now test is static. Is there a way to get it via cookie and replace it in the url?

Comment: You can fetch it from cookie or even configuration file & set later on

Comment: Thanks for the update. The issue now is that I have  no idea on how to actually change the tenant name. Do I do it in an actionfilter?

Comment: Yes, Actionfilter is one good place, you can create a custom action filter & use that for all views. Otherwise Route is itself actionfilter. If that name is static you can hard code in startup file too